# How to redirect url if the url don't exist?

Tags: wordpress

I want to redirect my url using 301, But the problem is that this page doesn't exist.

I've try this rule but it redirect
RedirectMatch 301 http://blog.example.com/my-slug/  http://www.example.com

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding this to your .htaccess file of blog.example.com:

Redirect 301 "/my-slug" "http://www.example.com"